# How to create a copy of an SQLite database table on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, database-migration

I am trying to create a **copy** of a database table in my Android project. Therefore, I increase the database version from `1` to `2` and run the following upgrade code:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2 && newVersion >= 2) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.execSQL("create table 'products_copy' as select * from 'products';");
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Migrating to version 2.");
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

I can see from the log output that the migration ran. Then I copy the database file from the device to my computer using *Android Studio's [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html)*. I can also see that the time stamp of the database file changed. When I open the database file with [*DB Browser for SQLite*](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser) the database however only contains the original `products` table - there is **no `products_copy` table**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `beginTransaction()` and `endTransaction()`, for three reasons:

1. You do not need them, as you are executing a single SQL statement.
2. You do not need them, as `onUpgrade()` is already wrapped in a transaction.
3. You are rolling back the transaction, as you never call `setTransactionSuccessful()`

If you remove those, your code should work, as I reproduced the findings in a sample project of my own.

Comment: Thank you. I just tested the upgrade without the transaction statements. The table copy is created :)